# How to sum up two different function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sum up two functions, which are part of the same object.

```
var player = {
stats: 0,
level: 1,
inventory: 30,
baseStrength: 5,
weaponStrength: 0,
armorStrength: 0,
accessoryStrength: 0,
totalStrength: function () {
    return (player.baseStrength + player.weaponStrength + player.armorStrength + player.accessoryStrength);
},
baseEndurance: 5,
weaponEndurance: 0,
armorEndurance: 0,
accessoryEndurance: 0,
totalEndurance: function () {
    return (player.baseEndurance + player.weaponEndurance + player.armorEndurance + player.accessoryEndurance);
},
baseAgility: 5,
weaponAgility: 0,
armorAgility: 0,
accessoryAgility: 0,
totalAgility: function () {
    return (player.baseAgility + player.weaponAgility + player.armorAgility + player.accessoryAgility);
},
baseDexterity: 5,
weaponDexterity: 0,
armorDexterity: 0,
accessoryDexterity: 0,
totalDexterity: function () {
    return (player.baseDexterity + player.weaponDexterity + player.armorDexterity + player.accessoryDexterity);
},
baseIntelligence: 5,
weaponIntelligence: 0,
armorIntelligence: 0,
accessoryIntelligence: 0,
totalIntelligence: function () {
    return (player.baseIntelligence + player.weaponIntelligence + player.armorIntelligence + player.accessoryIntelligence);
},
baseWisdom: 5,
weaponWisdom: 0,
armorWisdom: 0,
accessoryWisdom: 0,
totalWisdom: function () {
    return (player.baseWisdom + player.weaponWisdom + player.armorWisdom + player.accessoryWisdom);
},
baseLuck: 5,
weaponLuck: 0,
armorLuck: 0,
accessoryLuck: 0,
totalLuck: function () {
    return (player.baseLuck + player.weaponLuck + player.armorLuck + player.accessoryLuck);
},
experience: 0,
maxexperience: 100,
gold: 0,
health: 50,
maxhealth: function () {
    return ((player.baseEndurance + player.weaponEndurance + player.armorEndurance + player.accessoryEndurance) * 10);
},
mana: 50,
maxMana: function () {
    return (player.totalWisdom * 10 + player.totalIntelligence * 5);
},
manaRegen: function () {
    return (player.totalWisdom);
},
mindamage: function () {
    return Math.floor((player.totalStrength * 0.5));
},
maxdamage: function () {
    return (player.totalStrength * 0.8);
},
hpregen: function () {
    return Math.floor((player.totalEndurance));
},
accuracy: function () {
    return Math.floor((95 + (player.totalAgility * 0.05 + player.totalLuck * 0.1)));
},
defense: function () {
    return (player.totalDexterity * 1.2 + player.totalEndurance * 0.5);
},
evasion: function () {
    return (5 + (player.totalAgility * 0.5 + player.totalLuck * 0.15));
},
criticalChance: function () {
    return (player.totalAgility * 0.5 + player.totalLuck * 0.5);
},
criticalDamage: function () {
    return (player.totalStrength * 0.1 + player.totalDexterity * 0.1);
},
Lifesteal: function () {
    return (player.totalIntelligence / 100);
},
Lifesteal2: function () {
    return (player.totalIntelligence);
},
dropRate: 0,
expRate: 0
};
```

ok, so as you can see, I have 5 object properties for each stat, base/weapon/armor/accessory/total. Total is a function to sum up all of those stats.

After that we have player maxhealth, damage which are also functions which are calculated using "total" stat, but since its also a function I cant make it work. so the only way I figured out, is to instead of 
`(player.totalEndurance * 10)`

I have to do `((player.baseEndurance + player.weaponEndurance + player.armorEndurance + player.accessoryEndurance) * 10)`

and a part where I display it in html:

```
document.getElementById("maxhealth").innerHTML = player.maxhealth();
```

I add () since its a function, but its not working I get NaN result, function is either undefined or or "object is not a function" error.

I hope you can help me out :) thanks

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cwecuxhu/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part 2 (final):

To calculate using `totalEndurance` you need to add parenthesis to your call, because it's a function.

```
player.totalEndurance()
```

Part 1 (before comments):

I think something may be missing in your question.

When I put your player variable in to JSfiddle and then execute

```
document.getElementById("maxhealth").innerHTML = player.maxhealth();
```

everything works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/630jv67p/

Comment: because this part is actually `((player.baseEndurance + player.weaponEndurance + player.armorEndurance + player.accessoryEndurance) * 10);
},` I tested it to see if this works this way, but I want to use `player.totalEndurance * 10` instead

Comment: totalEndurance wasn't a variable defined in player of the original question. I see you added it as a function, so to access it you would need to do `player.totalEndurance() * 10` and anywhere else you want to reference it you would need to reference it as `player.totalEndurance()`

Comment: oh yeah -_- thanks, make an answer or edit it so I can accept ^^ thanks again